# Connect vertices using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using geometry nodes, I would like to connect some vertices loaded from a CSV file. Connect them using circle profile along straight lines formed by adjacent vertices. I have found examples doing this using a Bezier curve, for example, but can't get it work by having vertices only.

edit:
The vertices are ordered, so they should be connected in the order of the list containing them, eg, buy indices.

Can someone point me the right direction?
Thanks!

[image]

The final thing what I want to render is shown in these photos:

[image]
[image]

The blend file I made:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/120u7sHj1ZQCXYJxo8kjS-z4y0LpDWNmE/view?usp=sharing

File containing the coordinates:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19KqS3f0PGAy5zQPAjqcIEFPUEO5DQY1f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just a stupid question: Where does the information come from, which vertex should be connected to which one?

Comment: The vertices are ordered, so they should be connected in the order of the list containing them, eg, buy indices. I use them in OpenGL as LINE_STRIP. But, if you say that there is a more optimal type of order/list, then I can make it and use like that. I update my question, thanks for your time!

Comment: OK, and would it be possible that you also attribute these vertices with the information to which segment they belong? (e.g. outer ring, inner ring, etc.)

Comment: I don't quite understand the outer ring, inner ring part of the question. What I want is to draw a line that have thickness between adjacent vertices. I have updated my question again showing a photo what I want to render based on information from a CSV file.

Comment: In your last photo, the connections between nails are arbitrary. It doesn't look as if the nails were ordered and someone just connected the nails as connecting the dots. It looks as if someone designed a shape, and then inserted nails into that shape, and then just arbitrarily used various nails to put fill the shape with a string. It could be done in geonodes, but the setup needs more data than just nails. How would an automatic measure know that those areas aren't supposed to be filled? https://i.imgur.com/QZ7kqB5.png

Comment: The connections aren't arbitrary. They are in a specific order, just one continuous long string. I have a CSV which provides all the nail positions and also another CSV containing the positions where strings should be connected. The string (with variable thickness) itself what I want to make using geometry nodes. The final result I want to achieve is a realistic render, same as the provided photos.

Comment: I'd say it's not a geometry nodes problem at all - you need to load the data somehow, probably using Python, and the most straight-forward way to do it is to just directly make a mesh with edges defined in the CSV file.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will modify the CSV to have edge data.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, I did what you have suggested. I'm creating mesh with edge data as well. Also, updated my question with the blend file. Basically, what I need is to have a circle profile along the edges.

Comment: You didn't update the CSV file, and considering it's pairs of coordinates, I imagine it's just points. Whereas you need to define edges as input - you can figure out the edges inside geonodes, but then it will be just distance based and as I pointed earlier, the example photos don't look like the connections are (only) distance based.

Answer (score 1):

If your vertices are in the right order, just position curve points on them:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't show any result using my vertices. Also, curves not good for me, because the segments must be straight lines. I have updated my question with additional photos, what I want a realistic render from. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Ponzifex I don't know why Markus uses the node `Arc` here instead of `Curve Line` or `Mesh Line`, but if this example doesn't work for you, it's not because of this suggested solution. You get straight lines if you leave out the last two nodes. Maybe now would be the time for you to share your blend file with us so we can see what we are dealing with here.

Comment: @quellenform curves is my Achilles' heel, but I'd need to resample a *Curve Line*, right? A mesh line would have to be converted to a curve for auto handles, though the question edit reveals the answer as incorrect.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, absolutely correct, a `Curve Line` would have to be subdivided with `Resample Curve`. `Arc`, on the other hand, would be just a single node, but superfluous computational effort, strictly speaking (which is not tragic, though). And yes, `Mesh Line` would also require `Mesh to Curve`. ...but as you also rightly pointed out: Obviously an XY problem. ;-)

Comment: @quellenform I have added the .blend and the csv file to my question. Thanks!